# Ionic app unfortunately stopped on real android device

Tags: android-studio, ionic-framework, ionic3, apk

I have developed one app in ionic 3, which works fine in browser. Is it working good before Jun 16,2019. Now it is unfortunately stopped on android device.

After 16 june  is showing build error so I tried below steps

```
    ionic cordova platform rm android
    ionic cordova platform add android@8.0.0 
    ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-androidx 
    ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-androidx-adapter
    cordova plugin add cordova-android-support-gradle-release --save
```

then it is successfully built but 'Unfortunately stopped on device'.

Below is output of terminal

> 07-18 10:52:06.167 593-593/io.ionic.starter E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL
>   EXCEPTION: main
>       Process: io.ionic.starter, PID: 593
>       java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to get provider com.vaenow.appupdate.android.GenericFileProvider:
>   java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class
>   "com.vaenow.appupdate.android.GenericFileProvider" on path:
>   DexPathList[[zip file
>   "/data/app/io.ionic.starter-1/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/io.ionic.starter-1/lib/arm,
>   /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:6490)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.installContentProviders(ActivityThread.java:6082)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:6022)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1700(ActivityThread.java:211)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1766)
>           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6946)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
>           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1404)
>           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1199)
>        Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.vaenow.appupdate.android.GenericFileProvider" on path:
>   DexPathList[[zip file
>   "/data/app/io.ionic.starter-1/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/io.ionic.starter-1/lib/arm,
>   /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
>           at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
>           at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:511)
>           at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:469)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:6475)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.installContentProviders(ActivityThread.java:6082) 
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:6022) 
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1700(ActivityThread.java:211) 
>           at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1766) 
>           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
>           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145) 
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6946) 
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
>           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1404) 
>           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1199) 
>         Suppressed: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.vaenow.appupdate.android.GenericFileProvider
>           at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
>           at java.lang.BootClassLoader.findClass(ClassLoader.java:781)
>           at java.lang.BootClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:841)
>           at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:504)
>                 ... 13 more
>        Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Class not found using the boot class loader; no stack available

Please help me

Comment: Which error you get in your terminal?

Comment: @Fearcoder No any error is showing, just LAUNCH SUCCESS message is displayed

Comment: @Fearcoder is their any way to get error in terminal or log?

Comment: @Shreey you need to use android studio to load the app to a device and watch the logcat for errors.

Comment: use androidstudio and run it in emulator. If you launch, then you will be getting errors in the logcat. If you post that, we could able to help out

Comment: You can see it in your terminal

Comment: @Fearcoder,@cantona_7 Thanks, I have updated question with logcat.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same problem in the past what I did is this:

> 1. delete your node_modules folder manually
> 2. npm cache clean (doesnt not work in npm v5)
> 3. npm update
> 4. npm install

Try to reinstall android platform again. If this doesn't work I suggest to make a new ionic project with newest update and migrate all your files to the new one and test it again.

Best of luck!